# Why does my laptop see my wireless connection as two connections?

Tags: windows-vista, laptop, wireless-router

I have regular issues with my Dell Studio 1737, running Vista, with a D-link DIR-655 wireless router. I'll be working on it in the same room, signal is 99%, and I just lose network connectivity and cannot restore it until I reboot the router.

What's weird is that when I run "netsh wlan show all", I see my wireless router twice: Once with an SSID that is blank and one with my SSID showing up.  I don't broadcast my SSID, but my laptop knows to automatically connect to the network when it is in range and knows the SSID.

```
SSID 1 :
    Network type            : Infrastructure
    Authentication          : WPA2-Personal
    Encryption              : CCMP
    BSSID 1                 : 00:21:91:e8:82:51
         Signal             : 99%
         Radio Type         : 802.11n
         Channel            : 10
         Basic Rates (Mbps) : 1 2 5.5 6 11 12 24
         Other Rates (Mbps) : 9 18 36 48 54

SSID 3 : topsecret
    Network type            : Infrastructure
    Authentication          : WPA2-Personal
    Encryption              : CCMP
    BSSID 1                 : 00:21:91:e8:82:51
         Signal             : 99%
         Radio Type         : 802.11n
         Channel            : 10
         Basic Rates (Mbps) : 1 2 5.5 6 11 12 24
         Other Rates (Mbps) : 9 18 36 48 54
```

There are 7 networks in range in total, most of them with much weaker signals, and no channel conflicts  My network is the only one on Channel 10.

Is this normal to have it show up twice like this given my configuration, and could this be any indication of the problems of the laptop losing connectivity?

Answer (score 0):

The laptop detects the same BSSID twice because;

a. The access point exposes the same BSSID twice with different names.
b. The BSSID is saved twice with slightly different configuration*.

* *Control Panel  -> Network and Sharing Center -> manage wireless network*

Comment: Well, the information above seems to be identical and I've gone in and deleted the network(s) and let it re-find them. But it would still pop up. Recently, I was offered a hardware update for the wireless card through Windows update, so we'll see if it happens again. The update has actually resolved some unreliability with dropped connections.